# Is it possible to use the filename generated by previous code as the variable for next line of code?

Tags: vba, ms-word, savefiledialog

I have used vb to create two files that their names are based on the first line of each of their content. Now,  I want the two windows to be arranged vertically and thus use the "Windows.CompareSideBySideWith". But here is the problem---because of the two new files are "children" files of a "parent" file, and I want whenever the "parent" file change, the "Children" filename that "Windows.CompareSideBySideWith" call can change too.

Here are VBs code of Windows.CompareSideBySideWith

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
'
    Windows.CompareSideBySideWith _
        "Asbestos Exposures during Reprocessing of Automobile Brakes and Clutches"
End Sub
```

and the vb of two children file:
first

```
Sub savedoc()
'
' savedoc Macro
'
'

Dim oSection As Section
Dim r As Range
Dim TempDoc As Document
Dim FirstPara As String

For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    Set r = oSection.Range
    r.End = r.End - 1
    Set TempDoc = ActiveDocument
    With TempDoc
        .Range = r
        FirstPara = r.Paragraphs(1).Range.text
        FirstPara = Left(FirstPara, Len(FirstPara) - 1)
        .SaveAs FileName:=FirstPara & ".doc"
    End With
    Set r = Nothing
    Set TempDoc = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

the second one

```
Sub chinesenufi()
'
' chinesenufi Macro
'
'
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Copy

Dim oSection As Section
Dim r As Range
Dim TempDoc As Document
Dim FirstPara As String

For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    Set r = oSection.Range
    r.End = r.End - 1
    Set TempDoc = Documents.Add
    With TempDoc
        .Range = r
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        FirstPara = r.Paragraphs(1).Range.text
        FirstPara = Left(FirstPara, Len(FirstPara) - 1)
        .SaveAs FileName:=FirstPara & "chinese" & ".doc"
    End With
    Set r = Nothing
    Set TempDoc = Nothing
Next

End Sub
```

I would like the " Asbestos Exposures during Reprocessing of Automobile Brakes and Clutches" be able to change as any of the two "children" filename change
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried setting each "child" as an object variable in the "parent"?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "children" and "parent" files. Do you mean the content of the "parent" file has been copied to and saved to two other ("children") files and you want changes made to these two files to be reflected automatically in the "parent" file?

Comment: @Cindy Meister sorry, I didn't express my question well, but I accidentally solved my problem for some reason. I post my solving method in the Answer block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally get the solution as follows.

```
 Sub chinesenufi()
    '
    ' chinesenufi Macro
    '
    '
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.Copy

        Dim oSection As Section
        Dim r As Range
        Dim TempDoc As Document
        Dim FirstPara As String

        For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
        Set r = oSection.Range
        r.End = r.End - 1
        Set TempDoc = Documents.Add
        With TempDoc
        .Range = r
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        FirstPara = r.Paragraphs(1).Range.text
        FirstPara = Left(FirstPara, Len(FirstPara) - 1)
        .SaveAs FileName:=FirstPara & "中文檔" & ".doc"
        End With
        Set r = Nothing
        Set TempDoc = Nothing
        Next

        Dim objDoc1 As Word.Document
        Dim objDoc2 As Word.Document

        Set objDoc1 = Documents(FirstPara & ".doc")
        Set objDoc2 = Documents(FirstPara & "中文檔" & ".doc")
        objDoc1.Activate
        objDoc1.Windows.CompareSideBySideWith objDoc2
        Windows.ResetPositionsSideBySide


    End Sub
```

It seems that @ProfoundlyOblivious 's opinion that "setting each "child" as an object variable in the "parent" " works.